# How to change the final array to the front in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

The case is:

```js
function trocaPrimeiroEUltimo(array) {
    array.array[0]
    array.array[array.length - 1]
    return array
}
```

I did this way, but it didn't work. I can't change the structure of the function, just what it's inside. Someone, could please help me?

Comment: You access the values at the start and end, but don't use them at all - your function doesn't really _do_ anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to replace the last value with the first value?
if so, do:

```js
temp = array[0]

array[0] = array[array.length-1]

array[array.length-1] = temp
```

That's a simple swap.

Comment: amazing, you created a temporary element to solve it, thank youu

Answer (score 0):

The syntax makes use of new ES6 capabilities (destructuring an array). This way the exchange can be done without a temporary variable.

The whole thing can even be done as a one-liner:

```js
const arr=[7,8,9,10,11];

const swapFirstLast=(a,l)=>([a[0],a[l]]=[a[l=a.length-1],a[0]],a);

console.log(swapFirstLast(arr))
```

The use of the argument `l` is also something you probably would not do in a "real" application. I only went for it so I would not have to define the variable locally. `l` is assigned a value on the right hand side of the assignment expression. By the time the result needs to be stored `l` has been calculated and can also be used for addressing the right target element.

Comment: excellent!  I tried solving with one line using splice, but that became overly complex. The best thing about this solution is that it's easy to understand. +1